# In Elasticsearch, how do I search for an arbitrary substring?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

In Elasticsearch, how do I search for an arbitrary substring, perhaps including spaces?  (Searching for part of a word isn't quite enough; I want to search any substring of an entire field.)

I imagine it has to be in a `keyword` field, rather than a `text` field.

Suppose I have only a few thousand documents in my Elasticsearch index, and I try:

```
  "query": {
         "wildcard" : { "description" : "*plan*" }
  }
```

That works as expected--I get every item where "plan" is in the description, even ones like "supplantation".

Now, I'd like to do

```
  "query": {
         "wildcard" : { "description" : "*plan is*" }
  }
```

...so that I might match documents with "Kaplan isn't" among many other possibilities.

It seems this isn't possible with wildcard, match prefix, or any other query type I might see.  How do I simply search on any substring?  (In SQL, I would just do `description LIKE '%plan is%'`)

(I am aware any such query would be slow or perhaps even impossible for large data sets.)

Comment: You need to tokenize your description, in order to search for separate words. Have a read in their documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html

Comment: If you really want to search for an arbitraty substring, you need to go for ngrams: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ngrams_for_partial_matching.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search for a part of a word with ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467067/how-to-search-for-a-part-of-a-word-with-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hoping there might be something built-in for this Elasticsearch, given that this simple substring search seems like a very basic capability (Thinking about it, it is implemented as `strstr()` in C, `LIKE '%%'` in SQL, Ctrl+F in most text editors, `String.IndexOf` in C#, etc.), but this seems not to be the case.  Note that the regexp query doesn't support case insensitivity, so I also needed to pair it with this custom analyzer, so that the index matches all-lowercase.  Then I can convert my search string to lowercase as well.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "lowercase_keyword": { 
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword", 
          "filter": [ "lowercase" ] 
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": { 
     ...
     "description": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "lowercase_keyword"},
  }
}
```

Example query:

```
  "query": {
         "regexp" : { "description" : ".*plan is.*" }
  }
```

Thanks to Jai Sharma for leading me; I just wanted to provide more detail.

Comment: This is correct, but with field longer than 32766 it does not work:

original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 32804","caused_by":{"type":"max_bytes_length_exceeded_exception","reason":"bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 32804

any workarounds?

Comment: Got it, so, keep any value under 32K.  I assume it is UTF-8 by default?

Comment: i cant... theres a lot of workarounds but not a solution.

Comment: I still do not see a way to do a simple substring search except for via regexp on a keyword field with values under 32K.  I agree, it is limiting.

Comment: I have filed a elasticsearch issue here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/26759

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the **[regxp query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html)** in elasticsearch? It sure does sound like something you might be interested in.

Comment: Was hoping there might be something simpler in elastic, given that this simple substring search seems like a very basic capability.